# Multiple optional parameter ordering issues

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want Result like:

```php
Route::get('blogs', 'Blogs@index')->name('blogs');
Route::get('blogs/{section?}/{category?}', 'Blogs@index');
```

example:

```
Blogs/
Blogs/section
Blogs/category
```

Controller :

```php
public function index($section= '', $category= '', Request $request)
{

}
```

When i pass second para controller take it as first ( section )

Comment: refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182717/how-to-implement-array-type-route-in-laravel

Comment: Not a Laravel person so just asking if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749043/laravel-5-multiple-optional-parameters-in-route helps (should mark as Dupe if it does).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 multiple optional parameters in route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749043/laravel-5-multiple-optional-parameters-in-route)

Comment: what are these parameters doing? what do they serve for in the index function? is by searching, filtering, ordering?

Answer (score 0):

The order matters. Use this instead:

```
Route::get('blogs/{section?}/{category?}', 'Blogs@index');
Route::get('blogs', 'Blogs@index')->name('blogs');
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Why not pass as GET parameter the things that you are looking for? Doing so, you just need to check inside the `index()` function if you have any of them, and act according to them:

```
Route::get('blogs', 'Blogs@index')->name('blogs');
```

example:

```
Blogs?section=any-section&category=any-category
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request): Response
{
    if ($request->section) {/**/}
    if ($request->category) {/**/}
    // ...
}
```

Comment: blogs/passed_value      how to know that passed value is section or category in controller. if i pass category and section = null  so controller take category as a section parameter

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this is to check if the input matches a section or category and then call the right controller.

**For example:**

```php
Route::get('blogs/{slug}', function ($slug) {
   // Check if this is a section
   if (SectionModel::where('slug', $slug)->first()) {
        return \App::call('\App\Http\Controllers\Sections@index');
   }

   // Check if this is a category
   if (CategoryModel::where('slug', $slug)->first()) {
        return \App::call('\App\Http\Controllers\Categories@index');
   }

   // Section or category doesn't exist
   abort(404);
});
```

Comment: if section and category have same name for example section = colleges category = colleges

Comment: @divakar It depends on you, one of them must have priority.